# Make the whole paragraph appear on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to make the paragraph appear on hover. But when I try putting the code below, the whole paragraph is not appearing, it just shows some of the contents. What I want to happen is for the whole paragraph to appear on hover and all of the words are visible.

I am making a site on Weebly for a school project with relatively small knowledge. Is there anyway to make it work?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <br><br>
  <div class="tooltip">Word
    <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus, leo sit amet maximus finibus, quam justo interdum dolor, ac auctor mi elit eu nisi. Praesent vel facilisis mi. Nulla non ligula eget nunc euismod consectetur porta a elit. Pellentesque sodales ipsum nibh, at pretium mi vehicula luctus. Morbi dapibus felis vitae dolor ultrices dapibus. Sed vestibulum a augue id ultricies. Etiam mi diam, hendrerit a quam id, convallis molestie urna. Nullam facilisis elit sit amet lobortis malesuada. Donec lacinia ante turpis, id laoreet risus egestas scelerisque. Aliquam at iaculis nisl. Donec nec venenatis neque. In mollis mauris laoreet pellentesque efficitur. Proin feugiat elit sit amet lacus commodo luctus. Donec rhoncus ipsum vel nibh feugiat, eget feugiat justo volutpat. Aenean et nunc nunc.</span>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, since it appears to work fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/fbrx59mz/ (Well, the element is not fully visible, because it goes outside of the top of the viewport - but the _principle_ definitively works.)

Comment: I want to make the whole paragraph appear on hover, where all of the text appear on the visible screen upon hover.

Comment: But there isn't enough space above the trigger element, to display the whole text in an element that is only 120px wide ... So you will either have to move the trigger element further down the page, or make the text element wider. Or involve JavaScript, if you need a "dynamic" solution that checks how much space the element needs, and then decided whether to show it above or below the trigger.

Comment: The `<center>` tag is deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your text is being cut off from the top because of `bottom:100%;` it is fixing the bottom of the text container to the top of tooltip and if there is not enough space on top of tooltip, it will go outside the html page because it is `position:absolute`. So, make sure there is enough room on top of the **tooltip**
or position the content in a way that when it is visible it has enough space,check the code below, I have used `top:0;` I have also removed the `<center>` tag as it is depreciated and added some styling on the body:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      min-height: 100dvh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .tooltip {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }
    
    .tooltip .tooltiptext {
      visibility: hidden;
      width: 120px;
      background-color: black;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tooltip">Word
    <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I feel `top:100%;` is a better choice than `top:0;` in most cases. Depends on your design. Hope this helped..

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is that the tooltip text is overflowing and not being displayed properly. To make it work, you can add the following CSS rules to your code:

```css
.tooltip {
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text wrapping */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  white-space: normal; /* Allow text wrapping within the tooltip */
}
```

By adding **white-space: nowrap;** to the **.tooltip** class, you prevent the text from wrapping within the tooltip container. This ensures that the entire paragraph is visible on hover.

By adding **white-space: normal;** to the **.tooltip .tooltiptext** class, you allow the text within the tooltip to wrap if it exceeds the width of the container.

Here's the updated code with the additional CSS rules:

```css
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent text wrapping */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal; /* Allow text wrapping within the tooltip */
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<center>
  <br><br>
  <div class="tooltip">Word
    <span class="tooltiptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent cursus, leo sit amet maximus finibus, quam justo interdum dolor, ac auctor mi elit eu nisi. Praesent vel facilisis mi. Nulla non ligula eget nunc euismod consectetur porta a elit. Pellentesque sodales ipsum nibh, at pretium mi vehicula luctus. Morbi dapibus felis vitae dolor ultrices dapibus. Sed vestibulum a augue id ultricies. Etiam mi diam, hendrerit a quam id, convallis molestie urna. Nullam facilisis elit sit amet lobortis malesuada. Donec lacinia ante turpis, id laoreet risus egestas scelerisque. Aliquam at iaculis nisl. Donec nec venenatis neque. In mollis mauris laoreet pellentesque efficitur. Proin feugiat elit sit amet lacus commodo luctus. Donec rhoncus ipsum vel nibh feugiat, eget feugiat justo volutpat. Aenean et nunc nunc.</span>
  </div>
</center>
```

With these changes, the tooltip text should appear properly on hover, and the entire paragraph should be visible within the tooltip container.

Comment: Its' still not working for me. The whole paragraph is still not showing

Comment: Just a small note: the center tag is now deprecated, use CSS instead and br as a means of positioning is not very general purpose. On a more significant note, your snippet appears not to show the tooltip (I'm on Windows10/Edge). Could you test it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Both of your answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.